# EMC according to IEC60335 or to IEC55014

Tags: emc

I'm a bit confused about the IEC60335 and the IEC55014, since both seem to regulate the EMC conformity for household appliances. What I see in the IEC60335 are extremely high test values (EFT level 4, surge level 4 etc.) and in the IEC55014 the test values are way lower (EFT level 2, surge level 2 etc.).

What I see in most declaration of conformity for household equipment is, that it is tested according the IEC60335 for electrical safety and EMC according the IEC55014. How it comes, that one can choose the test criteria?

For Example:
Treadmill: https://download.nautilus.com/pdf/conformity/NLS_DOC_BFXT216.pdf
Vacuum cleaner: https://oldmedia.dyson.com/medialibrary/Files/Dyson/Support/downloads/UK/floorcare/EU%20DoC%20Dyson_RB01_2017_05_25_EN

Comment: I haven't used either of these but for what it's worth, only IEC 60335 seems to be harmonized below the LVD in Europe/EU (CE marking). Which doesn't rule out the other one in case some harmonized standard uses it as reference. Where in the world will your product be used?

Comment: The product will be used in europa. The thing is, the EMC test cases in the IEC60335 are way higher than for any medical/heavy industrial environment in terms of immunity. That does not make really any sense.

Comment: I suspect it depends on what voltage you supply the device with. You probably have to narrow it down to particular set of requirements for a certain kind of product. That's where consulting a test house comes in handy, because they have the experience of what's required by similar products.

Comment: I don't have access to any of these standards, but I can see that 60335 is harmonised to LVD and 55014 to EMCD. And you are only referring to surge tests etc, which are potentially harmful. Could it be that 60335 only requires the device not to catch fire etc (ie. it shall be safe in the event of such surge) but 55014 requires the device not to break at the lower level?